# Storing data from Twitter API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-gem

Before I begin, I'm still learning the whole MVC frame work so please be understanding in your explanations.

I am making a call to the Twitter API using the Twitter Gem.  Im gathering all of my followers and returning their names and gender using the genderize.io ruby gem extension.  I am displaying the names and percentage of genders "male, female, unknown" on my index view.

My final bit of code returns the breakdown into a JSON object.

```
"{\"male\":{\"count\":59,\"percent\":0.46},\"female\":{\"count\":31,\"percent\":0.24},\"unknown gender\":{\"count\":38,\"percent\":0.3}}"
```

My question is how do I refactor this long index method and break this down so that the model can store the data that I am getting back from the API and the gender breakdown?  In other words I need to store the Screename (screen_name), list of followers (@user_name), and gender percentage (@gender_percentage).

If anyone has any idea of how to begin breaking this down and where to being storing the data please let me know

My code is displayed here.

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
require 'twitter'
require 'json'


def index
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = '************'
  config.consumer_secret = '************'
  config.access_token = '************'
  config.access_token_secret = '************'
  end



 screen_name = 'myscreenname'
    follower_ids = client.follower_ids(screen_name)
    user_name = []
        follower_ids.each_slice(100) do |slice|
            begin
                client.users(slice).each do |user|
                    user_name << user.name
                end
            end
        end
    @user_name = user_name


c = user_name.map{|str| str.split.first}
gen = []
gir = GenderizeIoRb.new
c.each do |res|
 begin
 res = gir.info_for_name(res)
    gen << "#{res[:result].gender}"
    rescue
        res = "GenderizeIoRb::Errors::NameNotFound"
        gen << "uknown gender"
    end
end
hash = Hash.new 0
gen.each do |mfg|
    hash[mfg] += 1
end
count = hash.to_a
sum = 0
count.each { |_, v| sum += v }
gender_percentage = []
count.each do |k, v|
    gender_percentage << [k, ((v.to_f / sum) * 100).round]
end
@gender_percentage = gender_percentage

total = count.map { |elt| elt[1] }.reduce { |x, y| x + y }

hsh = {}
count.each do |label, n|
hsh[label] = {}
hsh[label]['count'] = n
hsh[label]['percent'] = (n.to_f / total.to_f).round(2)
end
hsh.to_json
end
end
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what is coming from twitter and what you want to output? You probably want to use the JSON.parse method. That will convert the JSON object into the normal ruby data types for you.

Comment: Understand that but how would I setup a model and refactor this so the model would store the data types is my question.  I already have the output the way I want it.